# Div repositioning in responsive web design

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.floatleft {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
.floatright {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #div1 {
        float: none;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" class="floatleft">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="floatleft">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="floatleft">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="floatright">Div 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm doing my first RWD project and I'm struggling to understand how the repositioning of divs work upon resize.

In my code example, on resizing to 800px div1 will move above all the other divs, which is what I want, but what I'm finding difficult is how would I move div4 to the right of div1 as per my picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap divs 1, 2 and 3 in a parent div that is floating left. Then your div 4 can float right on its own. Adjust the widths accordingly.

```
<div id="parent" class="floatleft">
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="floatleft">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="floatleft">Div 3</div>
</div>
<div id="div4" class="floatright">Div 4</div>
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1j7yh21/)

Comment: I actually answered my own question by moving div4 above div1, but the code I posted wasn't exactly what I was trying to achieve in my page, nevertheless, your suggestion is exactly what I need to do. D'oh, so simple!

Comment: @DanielWilliams, you shouldn't have your top most div float right.

Answer (score 1):

you are sort of on the right foot, you need to only call the pull-right class on div 2 and have it on the first one, the div one will have display default which is block and the other 2 will have display inline to be next to each other.

```
    <div id="div4" class="floatright">Div 4</div>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:inline;">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:inline;">Div 3</div>


div{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:inline;
}

.floatright {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
```

see fiddler

[Demo fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/e1nndwpm/2/)

Comment: You shouldn't float you top most div to the right. It is bad practice. By default everything is left aligned. Therefore you would be throwing off the default structure of the DOM and writing unnecessary code.

Comment: To map the picture he posted you need to do this, this could be embed inside another div, I tried to research this practice but I couldn't find it can you share a link please, because all I know is that bootstrap use it in pull-right class.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a percentage width for both, div1 having say 80% width and div4 having say 20% width? Although, div4 will have to be below div1 in the html for that to work.

Do you not have any widths set right now?